# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 on MacBookPro11,3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, ubuntu-13.10

I've been trying to install different flavours of Ubuntu on my `MacBookPro11,3` (15-inch) and nothing seems to work. Once I pass the Grub bootloader stage, all I'm getting is a blank screen.

I've seen some issues with installing Ubuntu on Apple's new Haswell-based hardware, so I assume that's the cause. I've installed Ubuntu just fine on previous Apple hardware.

If it helps, I've booted into recovery mode and this is the state I get stuck at:
[Recovery Mode Boot Screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/372239/IMG_20140518_225914.jpg)

Has anyone else had this problem when installing Ubuntu onto the recent Macbook Pros?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. Stay away from the i386 image. The amd64 image, like from [this page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/), actually works.